# DAX: Get latest date from certain point in time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a flat table displaying orders in time, the orders have an id and may change over time only changing the log_date for the order.

```
order_id   qty   log_date
1           3     2018-03-03
1           2     2018-01-06
1           4     2017-12-04
1           6     2017-10-10
2           1     2018-02-01
2           3     2018-01-04
2           2     2018-01-02
2           4     2017-12-01
```

My goal is to use a slicer so I can look at order status at a specific moment in time. If slicer is set to "2018-01-01" expected result would be id=1, qty=4 and id=2, qty=1. I've tried using a calculated table but they are not recalculated when slicer is changed.

```
TEST = 
VAR TheDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer, DATEVALUE("2000-01-01"))
RETURN
SUMMARIZE (
    Blad1,
    Blad1[order_id],
    "The_Qty", CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Blad1[qty] ),
        TOPN (
            1,
            FILTER ( VALUES ( Blad1[log_date] ), Blad1[log_date] <= TheDate ),
            [log_date], DESC
        )
    )
)
```

Is there a solution for this?

Regards.

Comment: Why `id=2`, `qty=3`?

Comment: My bad, should off course be id=2, qty=1

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me either. Shouldn't it be 4, the last `qty` on or before 2018-01-01?

Answer (score 0):

A calculated table is not responsive to slicers. You need a measure and a separate table for your slicer.

Create a new table for your date slicer. You can use `CALENDAR()` or `CALENDARAUTO()`.

```
DateSlicer = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Create a measure to pick out the rows you want:

```
RowFilter = 
    VAR SlicerDate = MAX(DateSlicer[Date])
    VAR LastLogDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Blad1[log_date]),
                          FILTER(ALL(Blad1),
                              Blad1[order_id] = MAX(Blad1[order_id]) &&
                              Blad1[log_date] <= SlicerDate))
    RETURN IF(MAX(Blad1[log_date]) = LastLogDate, 1, 0)
```

Now if you create a table or a matrix with the `order_id`, `qty`, and `log_date`, you can use this measure in the visual level filters section so it only shows rows where `RowFilter = 1`.